# How to merge data in storage class?

Tags: android

I am deveoping an app in which I have a class names as DataStorage, Now Initailly I send request to server and count data which is coming from server and set in Data storage class,Scenareo is something like that 1st request I count data from server like 5 and set it in data storage class,and 2nd time I count the data from server like 5 and set it also in Data storage class, but when I get Count from data storage it will return me 5 instead of 10.how can I do that

```
public static CLastCountData m_oLastCountData;

public static int getS_szLastCount() {
    return s_szLastCount;
}

public static void setS_szLastCount(int s_szLastCount) {
    CLastCountData.s_szLastCount = s_szLastCount;
}

public static int s_szLastCount;

public static CLastCountData getInstance() {
    if (m_oLastCountData == null) {
        m_oLastCountData = new CLastCountData();
    }
    return m_oLastCountData;
}
```

code from activity

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response
                        s_oDataset.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                            JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                            item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                            item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                            item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                            item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                            item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                            s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

                        }
                        arrayCount = posts.length();
                        CLastCountData.getInstance().setS_szLastCount(arrayCount);
                        Log.e(TAG,"ArrayCount::"+arrayCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
public static void setS_szLastCount(int s_szLastCount) {
    CLastCountData.s_szLastCount=CLastCountData.s_szLastCount+s_szLastCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to save your data in db after first call and retrieve this data after second call and add the second call data with db data.

Steps:

1. make 1st service call and save data in db
2. make 2nd service call and retrieve db data (which we saved after 1st service call).

   3. call getS_szLastCount() method and add 2nd service call data , and then call setS_szLastCount() to set the final result in class and save final result in db